# A iOS mobile webelement becoming non clickable when user goes two steps away from the page and try to comeback

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-java

> I have a Flutter app, which I believe comes under native app on iOS
> device with Appium 2.0beta66, java_client 8.5, JDK 15.

I have a **pageA** with with a **link A,** by clicking which I go in to pageB with 3 **links B1,B2,B3**, each would take me to pageC Now after clicking link A, going to pageB, I successively click **links B1**, go to pageC, then come back to **pageB** by tapping on a back button. So after going to **pageC** for **3 times** by clicking on **links B1,B2,B3 one after another**, and coming back to pageB each time. Finally after all this exercise was complete, when I am in pageB, I try to click a back button nothing is happening. Also by using the methods **isDisplayed(), isEnabled()** on the back button, I get **is_displayed=false, is_enabled=true** but **could NOT able to click it**.  This same back button is working fine, if I go to page B and try to come back to pageA in other test cases. In many other places even though the button exhibits the same attributes nonetheless is clickable. Basically 1 step out and back is working, but 2 steps out and back is NOT working.

**I believe, by going through pageA–>pageB–>(3times)pageC, the back button on pageB has lost the reference in the DOM structure. But it is not throwing any StaleElementException??.**

I waited on the back button for 20sec, 40sec, but in vain. But it is returning is_displayed=false, is_enabled=true. In many other places even though the button exhibits the same attributes nonetheless is clickable.
The locator I was using for this back button are(both not working).Neither any StaleElementException nor any general Exception is thrown.

-

@iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "Back")

public WebElement backBtn;

- (AND/OR)

  ```
   @iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSNsPredicate = "type == 'XCUIElementTypeButton' AND visible == 1 AND (name == 'Back')")
   public static WebElement nonClickableBackBtn;
  ```

How to resolve this issue ?
Thanks in advance for the help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy but I can't understand why it is work for the sake of God, solution was found. It is calling the same click the back button method twice in succession. wow !
It is working consistently.

```
nonClickableBackBtn.click();
nonClickableBackBtn.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the back button is enabled but not visible, then maybe something is overlapping it on page B or after moving to previous page? Can you check the structure in Safari Technology Preview and maybe paste it here?
Also, if you switch context to webview, you can use typical web xpath's instead of @iOSXCUITFindBy, which could give you more options in building a locator.